# Undefined control sequence. [$$\underset]

Tags: undefined, control

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}
$$\underset {{x}_1,{h}_1,{m}_2,{b}_2}{max} {u}_1(x)_1-{h}_1+{\beta}_1{W}_2({m}_2,{b}_2)$$

\end{document}
```

This is the problem I met, sublime text can display the equation but when I run this code, a warning `"Undefined control sequence. [$$\underset]"` showed.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome! You should not use `\underset` here but the `\max` operator. Nor should you use `$$ ... $$` but `\[ ... \]` instead. (I am also wondering why you wrap so many symbols in `{...}`.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\[\max_{x_1,h_1,m_2,b_2} u_1(x)_1-h_1+\beta_1W_2(m_2,b_2)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `\underset` command requires `amsmath`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % <----- don't forget

\begin{document}

\[
\underset{x+y+z}{a+b+c+d+e+f+g}
\]

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, you *don't* need `\underset` for your case, as [already suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542524/4427). The “max” operator is obtained with the command `\max` and

```latex
\[
\max_{1\le k\le n} x_k
\]
```

will yield the expected output.

I keep seeing code plagued with `\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{lim}`, where the simpler

```latex
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}
```

would suffice, besides producing a better output.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

       $$\underset {{x}_1,{h}_1,{m}_2,{b}_2}{max} {u}_1(x)_1-{h}_1+{\beta}_1{W}_2({m}_2,{b}_2)$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please write `\max`, not `max`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is bad advice.